# difference between class.prototype.property and object.property

Tags: javascript, oop

what is the significance of using prototype ? If i make a class as -

```
var myClass = function(){ this.p1 = 'p1';}
```

now if i want new property to be added as p2

i do it prototype property for the class and do it on object as well, like

using direct object ->

```
var obj = new myClass();
obj.p2 = 'p2';
```

using prototype ->

```
myClass.prototype.p2 = 'p2';
```

how these two are different? or are both lines different ?

Comment: Try to make two instances of your class and give the `p2` property different values. You'll immediately spot the difference.

Comment: thanks ! got the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype helps you, to have kind of inheritance (prototypal inheritance).
you can add properties to your objects manually, or borrow the property from its prototype. Let's take a look to some examples:

```
var obj = new myClass();
obj.p2 = 'p - child';
console.log(obj.p2); // p - child

var obj2 = Object.assign(obj.__proto__); // will borrow the value from the obj prototype
console.log(obj.p2); // p - child
```

Now take a look to what happen with myClass prototype:

```
var obj3 = Object.assign(myClass.prototype); //will borrow the value from the myClass prototype
console.log(obj3.p2); // p - parent
```

And here an example with not existing properties:

```
var obj4 = new myClass();
var obj5 = Object.assign(obj4.__proto__);

obj4.p3 = 'P3 - value';

console.log(obj4.p3); // P3 - value
console.log(obj5.p3); // undefined
```

Note: `__proto__` is for objects **{}**, prototype is for **functions**.

Hope this helps to clarify a little bit.

Comment: Please do not use the deprecated `__proto__` getter in explanations any more. Always use `Object.getPrototypeOf`.